# Randomly update columns with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a browser game which you can shoot missiles on factories.

This is example of a similar SQL table:

```
user_ID iron steel metal gold
   1     21    30   39    25
   2      7    10   25    50
```

I need each missile to destroy 1 factory.
For example I shoot 10 missile, so 10 factories are destroyed. But I need it to have completely randomly and even.
The problem is if according to this SQL table, if I shoot for example 40 missile on user_ID '2'.
In best case I destroy 10 factories of each kind. But how can I do it when I don't know if there is enough of each kind?

Comment: I think you can use `if` block in `php` and calculate the renaming resources each time someone shoot a missile. If resources goes to zero you are sure that factory is destroyed. And if only one resources goes to zero you can update the other

Comment: Did you mean to have `user_ID = 2` on the second line of the sample table?

Comment: It's no resources, its factorys. so each missle subtract only 1.
And 10 missles is just an example. if someone shoot 1000000 missles it will be really long loop.

Comment: @BarmarYes, I mean user_ID=2, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, divide the number of missiles by the number of factory types that have at least 1 factory. If all the types have at least this many factories, subtract this from each column.

If any of the types have less than this, they'll be totally wiped out. Reduce them to 0 and subtract their original totals from the number of missiles. Then start again, using just the remaining missiles.

Repeat this until you use up all the missiles or all factories are wiped out.

Comment: Thx, I though on something similar. But wouldn't it cause really long loop?

Comment: With 4 different types of factories, it will loop at most 4 times.

Comment: thank you! I would use that.